# Build a grid with time slots in multiple rooms

Tags: entities

I need to build a grid for one day (Feb. 27) that allows users to reserve time-slots. There are 12 1/2 slots with a limit of 8 bookings for each slot (in 8 different rooms). The users are authenticated...this is not open to the public.

I'm guessing this is possible with Calendar module and Jquery without having to install another module. Any ideas?

---

Drupal 7

Comment: Would Entity Registration work for this item?

Answer (score 0):

The bat module - https://www.drupal.org/project/bat would work for this use case without any custom code required.